# How to take data from DB table put into entity that has an inherited class with EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a SQL view that I am pulling in with entity framework. The view represents two existing objects that are joined together. I figured the best way to do this would be to have object inherit the other object.

I'm getting this error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error
>   occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner
>   exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.

Here is what I have setup:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>()
     .ToTable("mySQLView", "TEST")
     .HasKey(r => new { r.Property1 });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>().Property(r => r.Property1).HasColumnName("Key1");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>().Property(r => r.Property2).HasColumnName("Column2");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>().Property(r => r.Property3).HasColumnName("Column3");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>().Property(r => r.Property4).HasColumnName("Column4");
}
```

Here are my two classes:

```
public class Class1 : Class2
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
    public string Property4 { get; set; }
}
```

Class2 is being utilized by separate DB calls. Class1 is only being used in one of those calls. Any help on how to structure my classes or setup EF correctly would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using TPH (Table Per Hieararchy) that is a way that EF uses to implement inherithance. Using TPH EF needs a column named discriminator to associate the record with a specific entity of the hierarchy.

In your case I think you need TPT (but it depends on what you want access to classes). To do it just set the name of the Class2 table (or view) using `ToTable`. Otherwise you can add `Discriminator` column but you should leave EF to handle it.

Comment: These methods were helpful and got me closer to a solution. Although, after talking with my team, we decided to just duplicate the properties. Even though they have the exact same structure and naming conventions, the two views are two separate sets of data in separate databases.